# i2c_smbus_* functios don't exsit on centos7 i2c-dev.h

Tags: c++, linux, i2c

I nedd to manage a SMBus device from a Linux C++ program.

I can open the device (/dev/i2c-0), but I shaw that all i2c_smbus* functions (i2c_smbus_write_word_data, i2c_smbus_read_word_data etc..) are not declared in any i2c header.

i2c Documentation said that these functions are declared in linux/i2c-dev.h header but in my centos7 are not there.

I was looking for them in all headers but are not defined in any file.

Any idea about why are not defined there and where are they?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!

    int Address = 0x39; //Slave addr 

     char i2c_dev_node_path[] = "/dev/i2c-0";

     int ret_val = 0;
     /* Open the device node for the I2C adapter of bus 0 */
     i2c_dev_node = open(i2c_dev_node_path, O_RDWR);
     if (i2c_dev_node < 0)
     {       
         cout << "EROR Unable to open device node." << endl;
         return -1;
     }


     int i2c_dev_address = 0x39;

     ret_val = ioctl(i2c_dev_node,I2C_SLAVE,i2c_dev_address);
     if (ret_val < 0)
     {
         perror("Could not set I2C_SLAVE.");
         cout << "EROR Could not set I2C_SLAVE." << endl;
         return -1;
     }

     cout << "ALL OK!!!!!" << endl;


   int retVal = i2c_smbus_read_word_data ( i2c_dev_node , 0xac );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy i2c-smbus.ko  in /lib/modules/4.8.28-release/kernel/drivers/i2c/i2c-smbus.ko

```
yum install libi2c-dev
```